# Stored Procedure call in MVC 4 EF5 Not returning the correct data

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures

I'm calling a stored procedure that is creating a randomly generated temp password for new users for a internal system. I have and call other stored procedures and they work just fine. For some reason this one is returning  `"System.Data.Objects.ObjectResult1[System.String]"` when it should be return something like this, `UtUdHUVx7fCu`.

I have tried changing `<usp_GeneratePassword_Result>` in the Context.cs to just `<string>` but that gives me the same error.

**SP**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_GeneratePassword]

@PasswordLength INT

AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @SourceString VARCHAR(100)
SET @SourceString = 'abcdefhkmnpqrstuvwxyzABCDEFHJKMNPQRSTUVWXYZ23456789'

SELECT (
    SELECT  TOP (@PasswordLength)
            SUBSTRING(@SourceString, 1 + (CAST(ROUND(RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) * 1000, 0) AS INT) % LEN(@SourceString)), 1)
    FROM    sysobjects
    FOR     XML PATH('')
) AS GeneratedPassword


END
```

**Controller**

```
    private AdventureWorksEntities db = new AdventureWorksEntities();
    ^^ this is at the top 

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Register(mvcUser model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            var pass = db.usp_GeneratePassword(10);
            model.UserPassword = pass.ToString();

            db.mvcUsers.Add(model);
            db.SaveChanges();
            ModelState.Clear();
            model = null;

        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return RedirectToAction("index","Home");
    }
```

**Model**

```
    public partial class usp_GeneratePassword_Result
{
    public string GeneratedPassword { get; set; }
}
```

**Context.cs**

```
        public virtual ObjectResult<usp_GeneratePassword_Result> GeneratePassword(Nullable<int> passwordLength)
    {
        var passwordLengthParameter = passwordLength.HasValue ?
            new ObjectParameter("PasswordLength", passwordLength) :
            new ObjectParameter("PasswordLength", typeof(int));

        return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<usp_GeneratePassword_Result>("GeneratePassword", passwordLengthParameter);
    }
```

[image: Image for reference]
again if i am missing anything please let me know.

[image: At break point]

Comment: are you calling the correct procedure? Everything here is about password but you are calling `usp_GenerateUsername`

Comment: Sorry edited it. i have two SP doing the same this and I deleted the wrong one when Copy and pasting. usp_GeneratePassword is the correct one

Comment: OK. Incidentally, why wouldn't you use C# for this? Seems inefficient and less random to go to the database than to use `RNGCryptoServiceProvider`

Comment: The SP is working fine for me. Have you set a break at `model.UserPassword = pass.ToString();` to see the value of `pass`?

Comment: @Crowcoder - I agree that its inefficient but higher up want it in a SP.

Comment: @WEI_DBA I added a screen shot of what the break point looks like.

Comment: So it looks like it's returning what you want.

Comment: normally it would return a value like you can see in the first image, ex: `EmailId = "test@gmail.com"`. I guess my problem is how do i access the Result View value. or if that is even an option.

Comment: Hmmm. Not sure, but would `pass[0].ToString();` this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your information is getting put into a list so you might want to try something like this.

```
 if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {

            var pass = db.usp_GeneratePassword(10).ToList();
            model.UserPassword = pass[0];                

            db.mvcUsers.Add(model);
            db.SaveChanges();
            ModelState.Clear();
            model = null;

    }
```

Comment: I'm guessing that there is a nicer way of doing this with LINQ as well.